# How can you stop the borders of table cell elements overlapping the cell's padding area?

Tags: html, css

Table cell elements, that have borders, do not respect the vertical height of the cell that contains them. A child's borders my overlap the padding (and even the border) of its containing cell. How can this be prevented such that the cell completely contains the child element, including its border?

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mPMys/1/)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>foo bar</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

tr {
    background: red;
}
td {
    padding: 5px;
    background: white content-box;
}
span {
    border: 10px solid blue;
}
```

[image: Red = cell padding, blue = element border]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick `display: inline-block;` on the span.  The border will then be a block border rather than a line-box border and be forced to stay within the element's bounding box.

Something like that.  :)